# Can you bet sexual acts?

Tags: contract-law, is-x-legal, gambling, prostitution

I'm pretty sure you cannot make a bet and have the outcome one way or another be a sexual favor. But why would this be illegal?

Comment: In what context? Could you provide more information about how this would actually be applied in a real situation where *the law* would be concerned with it taking place? The only thing that comes to mind is a bunch of kids playing spin the bottle and other games at a party, in which case I doubt anyone cares if they're betting sexual favors while messing around at a party.

Comment: "Hey honey, if I make this three pointer... Oral sex. If I miss I'll do all household chores for a month." Cops come arrest me? One sues the other for breach?

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you interested in?

Comment: @Mark somewhere where prostitution is illegal, but sexual acts in general are all legal

Comment: As my elementary school English teacher would say, you certainly "can" do that, although it might not be legal to do so if you did.

Answer (score 4):

This would be entirely dependant on the jurisdiction.

The things that would need to be legal to make this transaction legal are:

1. Is the sexual act legal?
2. Is gambling legal?
3. Ongoing consent by both parties

To make this an enforceable contract, in addition you would need:

1. Sexual acts to be valuable consideration, basically, is prostitution legal?
2. The fundamentals of a binding contract: intention, legality of objects etc.

Comment: Also, the remedy for breach of such a contract would almost certainly not be specific performance, given that that could amount to rape.

Comment: why would prostitution have to be legal? Is betting something the legal equivalent of selling it?

Comment: @truth illegal acts may not form part of a contract's undertakings. However, whether prostitution is legal would depend on the statutory definition of prostitution in the relevant jurisdiction, and whether it being part of the contract (alongside the other terms of the proposed contract) fulfils that definition.

Comment: @jimsug i understand that illegal acts can't be part of the contract, but in general, sex is not illegal

Comment: @truth It really depends on the definition of prostitution. If fulfilment of your wager would constitute an act of prostitution, the contract is void.

Comment: @TruthOf42 prostitution comes in because betting is the risking of something of value for another thing of value - for a sex act to have  value in an economic sense it must be saleable. The selling of sex is prostitution

Comment: Must prostitution necessarily be legal for , basically, spin the bottle to be legal?

Comment: @Seekinganswers: for it to be a legally binding contract, yes, but spin the bottle isn’t meant to be a legally binding contract.

Comment: Why would ongoing consent have to necessary? I would assume then it would be rape, but if I bet money and they take it, it doesn't count as theft, even if I don't want them to

Comment: @TruthOf42 You can't consent in advance to sexual acts in modern criminal law, just as you can't consent in advance to specifically performable indentured servitude (except in connection with military service or paramilitary service like certain field officers of the CDC). People are not things in modern law.

Comment: @TruthOf42 A comedian explains some of the key concepts: https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1494770727697045

Comment: @TruthOf42 "_but if I bet money and they take it, it doesn't count as theft, even if I don't want them to_" Generally, if you've lost a bet, the other party can't "just take it"... you have a debt, and if you don't pay, they would have to sue.

Answer (score 3):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In most jurisdictions in the U.S. this would be unenforceable, and possible even a crime. (Many non-U.S. jurisdiction are more legally tolerant of both gambling and of prostitution, and I'm not familiar with those jurisdictions at a sufficient level of detail to answer regarding those places.)

First, most U.S. jurisdictions have a common law rule that contracts with meretricious consideration (i.e. where sex is one of the things that someone is contributing economically to the contract) are void as contrary to public policy.

Second, this would be considered prostitution in most jurisdictions as it is defined under local laws. Prostitution is illegal in essentially every jurisdiction but a few counties in Nevada and is regulated there in a way that wouldn't allow this kind of contract in those jurisdictions. The illegality of prostitution would make the contract unenforceable, and depending upon the definition of prostitution in a particular jurisdiction would also make it a crime.

Third, most U.S. jurisdictions prohibit gambling generally, subject to only narrow exceptions, most of which are regulated, and this would not fall within any of the common exceptions to the rule prohibiting gambling. Gambling is usually a misdemeanor or low level felony depending upon the nature of one's involvement.

This said, however, between consenting adults who have or are open to having a sexual relationship with each other, who would never consider seeking to enforce their bet legally, one of the stronger defenses legally would be to argue that it isn't what it superficially seems to be.

In other words, one could argue that this was not really a true "contract" or transactional sex, and was also not bona fide gambling, that would actually be enforced or considered binding by the participants, but was instead merely a form of role playing or informal adult play that isn't a genuine gambling or transactional sex transaction, even though it mimics the form of such an arrangement. If the implicit assumptions of the parties in context was that someone losing a bet could decline to perform the sexual act without consequences despite the seeming obligation arising from losing the bet, this defense could prevail. And, as a practical matter, this kind of activity would not be likely to be characterized as criminal conduct by people with knowledge of it, reported to authorities, prosecuted, or enforced in a civil lawsuit, if it was just silliness between friends as opposed to genuine commercial prostitution in bet form or genuine gambling with hard stakes that would be taken seriously and enforced extra-legally.